# Can't execute a JavaScript file compiled using the Rhino JavaScript Compiler

Tags: java, javascript, classpath, rhino, noclassdeffounderror

Alright, so I created a JavaScript file named `HelloWorld.js` with the following contents:

```
java.lang.System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

Now, I compiled it using the Rhino JavaScript Compiler using the following command (the `js.jar` file is in my classpath):

```
java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.jsc.Main HelloWorld.js
```

It compiled the JavaScript file and created the Java class file as expected. Then I tried to execute the Java class file by calling `java HelloWorld`. However, it generated the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: HelloWorld. Program will exit.
```

I tried to understand what caused the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` to be thrown, and from what I read in this [blog post](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) I learned that the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown if a class was present during compile time but not available in Java classpath during runtime.

So I ran the `javap HelloWorld` command to check what the problem is, and this is what I got:

```
public class HelloWorld extends org.mozilla.javascript.NativeFunction implements org.mozilla.javascript.Script {
    public HelloWorld();
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    public final java.lang.Object exec(org.mozilla.javascript.Context, org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable);
    public final java.lang.Object call(org.mozilla.javascript.Context, org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable, org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable, java.lang.Object[]);
    public int getLanguageVersion();
    public java.lang.String getFunctionName();
    public int getParamCount();
    public int getParamAndVarCount();
    public java.lang.String getParamOrVarName(int);
    public boolean getParamOrVarConst(int);
}
```

Now, what I understand from this is that the `HelloWorld` class is present and is declared as `public`. Hence there shouldn't be any reason why the Java Virtual Machine can't find it. This is where I'm confused. I don't know where to go from here, nor what to do to resolve this problem.

I found out that I could execute the Java class file if I invoked Rhino to call the `exec` method on an instance of `HelloWorld` as follows:

```
java -jar /usr/share/rhino/js.jar HelloWorld.class
```

However, I would like to execute the Java class file using the `java HelloWorld` command directly since the `js.jar` file already in my classpath. I would like to understand what the problem is so that I know what's really happening behind the scenes.

Comment: `JavaScript file named HelloWorld.java` o_O. Rhino executes `js` (javascript) files, not `Java` ones. In order to run `Java` programs, one doesn't need to have Rhino.

Comment: @kirilloid: In order to run Java classes compiled by Rhino, one needs the Rhino runtime library.

Comment: @Thilo Does Rhino compile `js` to `Java`?

Comment: It can compile to Java class files, yes. Note that the OP successfully created a HelloWorld.class that `javap` can read.

Comment: Then don't listen to me =) I thought, Rhino could only execute js files.

Comment: @kirilloid - Lol. Typo. I did save it as `HelloWorld.js`, but I wrote it as `HelloWorld.java` here. Honest mistake. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @AaditMShah The fact, `*.js` file contains java code still confuses me

Comment: @kirilloid - Rhino allows you to use access Java packages, classes, and interfaces using a feature known as `LiveConnect`. That's how I can use `java.lang.System` from a JavaScript file. AFAIK it only works in Rhino and (if I'm not mistaken) Spidermonkey. Cheers. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the class file is on the classpath (as well as js.jar)?

Try

```
java -cp .;js.jar HelloWorld
```

(assuming HelloWorld.class in the current directory, otherwise something like `-cp build;js.jar`).

Comment: I found out what the problem was. My `HelloWorld` class wasn't in the classpath. So I updated the following line in my `.bashrc` to reflect the change `export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/rhino/js.jar:$HOME/class`. Then I moved my `HelloWorld.class` file to `$HOME/class`. That solved the problem. When I executed `java HelloWorld` from the `class` directory it showed me the output without any errors. Thank you for your help. I just have one more question: why couldn't the Java Virtual Machine find my `HelloWorld.class` file when I was explicitly trying to execute it? I don't understand what happened.

Comment: The current directory is not necessarily in the classpath. I think, when you have other things set there, it will not be added unless you explicitly put it in. Try to avoid environment variables, and use `-cp` or runnable jar files or an IDE. Environment tends to leak into applications that don't need it and mess them up.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll continue using environment variables for development purposes. The good thing about `.bashrc` is that it only modifies the current user's environment variables. For production code I'll create a shell script which uses the `-classpath` option to explicitly set the classpath. =)